# AttributeTable sending an alert that data was not found when clicking on table row

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have an AttributeTable that I have opening when I start a widget.  When I click on a table row in this instance, I am able to get the information back correctly and not see this message.  I did this by changing the config.json file to have the primary field in the database to not show.

```
"name": "Current Parties",
"id": "Layer Id",
"layer":{
    "url": "url to Feature Server",
    "fields":[
        {
            "show": false,
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "alias": "OBJECTID"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the rest of the fields having the property set to true.  However, when I change the table and have it pulling back from a different database, I see the correct information, but when I click on a record in the table, I get this alert

[image]

Which should not be appearing since the new information is being displayed in exactly the same way.  Can anyone explain why this alert is still showing up?  If anything else needs to be added to better help diagnose the problem, let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tedious and failed attempts at trying to figure this out, I finally got it figured out.  Since the AttributeTable is an `off panel` widget, it is opened in a different way than `on panel` widgets.  Inside the AttributeTable widget.js file, the `open` method invokes `this._openTable()`.  Since my custom widget.js file also contains the `open` function, I simply needed to find the `off panel` widget I wanted to open and invoke the `panel._openTable()` method each time I wanted the AttributeTable to open and load the correct information.  So in the end, here's what I did.

In the open function in my custom widget file, I created a reference to my WidgetManager instance.

```
var wm = WidgetManager.getInstance();
```

I then got the reference and located the AttributeTable widget in the `loaded` object array.  At which point, I attached the `_openTable()` method to it.

```
wm.loaded[8]._openTable();
```

This loaded every layer and field with a property of true in the config.json file(I did some customization to hide and show certain tables each time I opened the table, but that's not pertinent to this question).  Since everything has been pre-loaded, I could close the table and re-open it and change which tables were showing in the AttributeTable widget.js file's `onReceiveData` function.  When it received the message that I had re-opened the widget, it knew which fields to show based on the customization I mentioned earlier.